# How to check if a floating point number is integer power of another number

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

```
function checkIfNumberIsPower(n,power) {
    if(n == 0) {
        return 0;
    }    
    var count = 0; 
    while(n != 1)
    { 
        console.log("hi")
        if(n % power != 0) {
           return false;
        }   
        n = n / power;   
        count++;  
    }
    console.log(count)
    return true;
}

var numb = 0.01;
var power = 10;
var numbCheck = checkIfNumberIsPower(numb,power);
console.log("numb is...."+numbCheck );
```

I am trying to check if number is power of 10. It works fine if numb is not a floating point number, but when I check a floating point number such as `0.01` it returns `false` (it should be `true` as `10^-2 = 0.01`).

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: If you are counting non-integers, aren't all numbers some power of 10? For example: `11.17` is roughly `1.272932331324498 ** 10`

Comment: @EmilVikström he's probably interested why the code does not print the expected result...

Comment: @kfx this is a  question.Instead of 10, we might need to check if number is power of 4 or not.

Comment: @Mark_M This is a generalized code which checks if a number is power of another number.It works fine if number is not decimal but for decimal number it gives incorrect result

Comment: I understand tha @Priyanka but you can take the nth root of any number, so all numbers are the power of any other number unless you restrict it to something like integers.

Comment: Can you not use `Math.log10` to check if its power of 10 or not?

Comment: @kfx I am trying to check if number is power of 10 or not. Example : take 100. It is a power of 10 (10^2). This works fine by my code. But if I write number like 0.01 which is also a power of 10.(10^-2) .It gives me false instead of true

Comment: Apparently you want to restrict to integer powers, including negative integer powers (for which it currently does not work). Is that so? Please update the question.

Comment: you may go into the trap of floating point arithmetik which does not give the precision of numbers which might be necessary for the calculation. for example if you take a logarithm to get the power, you get for the example `Math.log(n) / Math.log(power)` the value of `-1.9999999999999995`, which is not enough to use it as wanted `-2` as value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For preventing the trap of precision of floating point arithmetic, you could store the direction of needed multiplication or division with the power and check if the value reaches one.

For preventing an infinity loop, another check is made by using the direction for a direction depending check and exit if the value goes into the unwanted direction. This result may be interpreted as well as **not in power**.

For all other values which are not zero, the value of power is returned.

```js
function checkIfNumberIsPower(n, power) {
    var count = 0,
        direction = n < 1;

    if (!n) {
        return 'zero';
    }
    while (n !== 1) {
        if (direction) {
            n *= power;
            count--;
        } else {
            n /= power;
            count++;
        }
        if (direction ? n > 1 : n < 1) {
            return 'missing precision or not power';
        }
    }
    return count;
}

console.log(checkIfNumberIsPower(0.01, 10));
console.log(checkIfNumberIsPower(1000, 10));
console.log(checkIfNumberIsPower(1001, 10));

console.log(checkIfNumberIsPower(8, 2));
console.log(checkIfNumberIsPower(0.125, 2));

console.log(checkIfNumberIsPower(4, 3));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is probably good. I thought that no one is going to write the answer, so finally did it myself - just the same time as you.

Comment: power has to be a positive value. which result do you expect in this case?

Comment: actually no, but you could try some approaches and ask a new question, if stuck.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to do this check for integer numbers. So, in order to check it for floating point number we can invert the number, and then call the check for integer numbers. This might still lead to wrong results for some floating point values due to the limited precision, but works for as long as not too many digits are required.

```
function checkIfNumberIsPowerInt(n, power) {
    var count = 0;
    while(n != 1)
    { 
        if(n % power != 0) {
           return false;
        }   
        n /= power;   
        count++;  
    }
    return true;
}

function checkIfNumberIsPower(n, power) {
    if(n === 1) { // for all x, x^0 = 1
        return true;
    }
    if(!n) { // for no x, x^y = 0
        return false;
    }
    if(Math.abs(n) > 0 && Math.abs(n) < 1) {
        return checkIfNumberIsPowerInt(1 / n, power);
    }
    return checkIfNumberIsPowerInt(n, power);
}


console.log(checkIfNumberIsPower(0.01, 10));    // 10^-2 = 0.01
console.log(checkIfNumberIsPower(0.01, -10));   // -10^-2 = 0.01
console.log(checkIfNumberIsPower(-0.1, -10));   // -10^-1 = -0.1
console.log(checkIfNumberIsPower(-0.01, -10));  // -10^-2 =/= -0.01
```